# Possible to use an Async call return value to show/hide an alert?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, boolean

Before this gets closed as a dupe, i've been thru many items on the forum that dont answer my question so please read.

Scenario: user clicks a button.  javascript should validate whether the input date is valid or not.  If it's not valid, show a confirmation box so they can continue with the bad date TO THE SERVER FOR DB insert or update, or cancel and edit.

To do the date validation, i need to call a webmethod.  using an ajax call, since it's async, wont work because it doesnt wait for the result of the webmethod.  Due to setting the variable to false when declared, the "isdateValid" method always returns false and shows the confirmation box even when the date is valid (web method returns true).  I've added a callback function to handle the webmethod call but the messagebox has already been shown to the user before the webmethod returns.  The only way i can seem to make this "work" is to have this as a sync call instead of async.  Is there a way to make it "wait" besides making async: false?  This is really a synchronous piece of logic but all the forum posts say to avoid making it sync, so open to ideas.

```
function buttonClick(){
     if (!isDateValid())
          //show the confirmation box
}

function isDateValid(){
      var isDateValid = false;
      //ajax call to webmethod
}
```

---more detail, tried various things i've found...still not good.

user clicks "Post" button...check if date is valid, if not, show message box where they can continue to post or cancel

```
function checkPostConfirmation() {
if (!checkDateValidation())
    //show confirmation box
else
   //do something different  
   //always comes here because it's not "waiting"
}

//this method doesnt actually "wait"
async function checkDateValidation() {
    let result = await isChequeDateInvalid();
    return result;
}

 async function isDateInvalid() {
    var isDateValid = false;
    var selectedDate = (date from control on the screen)

    var result = await $.ajax
        ({
            ...typical stuff
            async: true,
            success: function(msg) {
                    callback(msg.d);
                }
        });                
    }

    function callback(boolResult) {
        isDateValid = boolResult;
    }

    return isDateValid;
}
```

Comment: *"i've been thru many items on the forum"* - Link them, show what you tried - back up your claim.

Comment: So cancel the form submission, make the call, if successful, resubmit the form with JavaScript.

Comment: How is this different from a simple js async method problem? Also have you tried callbacks?

Comment: ...and while you're doing that, have a look at [SO's "How to ask" FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), where *"Search, and research ...and keep track of what you find."* is in the first paragraph, and [*"Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is only a few paragraphs down.

Comment: You can't use a asp.net button that expects a true or false (and true means to THEN run the server side code). Your button code HAS to call js code. And then based on the result of the js code, you THEN can call the server code behind. You can't bind or tie a function directly to the existing asp.net button that expects a return true/false based on the ajax call. You can either hide the button with style="display"none" and then ADD  a new button. That button when clicked does not run server side code and does not have a server side event code stub. That button when clicked calls the js code.

Comment: the js code function thus will and can do the verification. and based on the result of the dialog box, then a ok code stub, an a cancel code stub will be run. If the ok js function is run, it is THAT function that can now click on the original button you had to run the server side event code stub for that button. You will wind up with 3 js routines. The one to call the web method, and two more (the ok result routine, and the cancel/bad/not ok routine. It is these two js routines based on the result of the first js routine called that can NOW have your button code stub run.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Javascript async/await,

```
function buttonClick(){
          isDateValid()
                  .then(result => {
                       if (!result)
                           //show the confirmation box
                   })
                  .catch(err => //handle error);
     
}

async function isDateValid(){
      var isValid = false;
      //ajax call to webmethod with await keyword
      isValid = await fetch(url);
      return isValid;
}
```

Comment: How does `isDateValid` return? I think thats what the OP is asking.

Comment: The ajax call return should set it, I updated my code.

Comment: Rajdeep Debnath - thanks for the comment.  I dont think i can use your code as my buttonClick function cant be async because that'll submit and send things over to the server.

Comment: @user3242116 I have updated the code and made it promise based, kindly check